# Koa and Stripe, wait to render page

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, koa

I'm using koa and stripe to process a one time payment. It's working as it should, however it renders the page before `data` gets assigned. I would like to be able to render the page after data is assigned so that `id` will show up in the page view instead of it being undefined.

I tried rendering the page in the callback function, I got a `404 not found`. I tried using `.then` after the `stripe.charges.create` function, since stripe is compatible with promises but it gave the same result. The current code I have is below.

```
    module.exports.payment = function* payment()
    {
        const params = this.request.body;
        let data;

        if (!params.stripeToken) {
            this.throw(400, "Sorry, something has gone awry.");
        }
        if (!params.amount) {
            this.throw(400, "A purchase amount must be supplied.");
        }
        const chargeAmount = params.amount * 100;

        const charge = stripe.charges.create({
            amount: chargeAmount,
            currency: "USD",
            source: params.stripeToken,
            description: `${config.site.name} order#: ${this.session.id}`
        }, (err, charge) => {
            data = charge.id;
        }

);

    yield this.render("payment/payment_success", {
        id: data
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stripe library supports promises, your best bet is probably to yield `stripe.charges.create`.

```
module.exports.payment = function* payment()
{
    const params = this.request.body;

    if (!params.stripeToken) {
        this.throw(400, "Sorry, something has gone awry.");
    }
    if (!params.amount) {
        this.throw(400, "A purchase amount must be supplied.");
    }
    const chargeAmount = params.amount * 100;

    const charge = yield stripe.charges.create({
        amount: chargeAmount,
        currency: "USD",
        source: params.stripeToken,
        description: `${config.site.name} order#: ${this.session.id}`
    };

    yield this.render("payment/payment_success", {
        id: charge.id
    });
};
```

Now when you render your view, charge will be populated with the results of your stripe call.